# Search and replace values in text file with C#

Tags: c#, search, text, replace

I have a text file with a certain format. First comes an identifier followed by three spaces and a colon. Then comes the value for this identifier.

```
ID1   :Value1  
ID2   :Value2  
ID3   :Value3
```

What I need to do is searching e.g. for `ID2   :` and replace `Value2` with a new value `NewValue2`. What would be a way to do this? The files I need to parse won't get very large. The largest will be around 150 lines.

Comment: you should specify type of Value1, Value2... Integer, string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file isn't that big you can do a `File.ReadAllLines` to get a collection of all the lines and then replace the line you're looking for like this

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

List<string> lines = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines("file"));
int lineIndex = lines.FindIndex(line => line.StartsWith("ID2   :"));
if (lineIndex != -1)
{
    lines[lineIndex] = "ID2   :NewValue2";
    File.WriteAllLines("file", lines);
}
```

Comment: Only problem with this is if his data above isn't accurate, and each new 'ID' value isn't on a new line.

Comment: then he could go for File.ReadAllText and parse the one big string, I'll put that example up if he says that's a problem; on the other hand.. he did say the file was 150 *lines*

Comment: Yes, each ID is definitely on a new line.

Comment: Though all variants seem to answer my question I chose this one as it gave me the idea of how to solve it :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution which also creates a backup of the source file automatically.

The replacements are stored in a `Dictionary` object. They are keyed on the line's ID, e.g. 'ID2' and the value is the string replacement required. Just use `Add()` to add more as required.

```
StreamWriter writer = null;
Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
replacements.Add("ID2", "NewValue2");
// ... further replacement entries ...

using (writer = File.CreateText("output.txt"))
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("input.txt"))
    {
        bool replacementMade = false;
        foreach (var replacement in replacements)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith(replacement.Key))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}   :{1}",
                    replacement.Key, replacement.Value));
                replacementMade = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!replacementMade)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}

File.Replace("output.txt", "input.txt", "input.bak");
```

You'll just have to replace `input.txt`, `output.txt` and `input.bak` with the paths to your source, destination and backup files.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the value of "Value2". In other words: I need to replace everything that's behind "ID2   :".

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, for any text searching and replacement, I'd suggest some sort of regular expression work, but if this is all you're doing, that's really overkill.

I would just open the original file and a temporary file; read the original a line at a time, and just check each line for "ID2   :"; if you find it, write your replacement string to the temporary file, otherwise, just write what you read. When you've run out of source, close both, delete the original, and rename the temporary file to that of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  It's very simple, not the most efficient thing, but for small files, it would be just fine:

```
private void setValue(string filePath, string key, string value)
{
    string[] lines= File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    for(int x = 0; x < lines.Length; x++)
    {
        string[] fields = lines[x].Split(':');
        if (fields[0].TrimEnd() == key)
        {
            lines[x] = fields[0] + ':' + value;
            File.WriteAllLines(lines);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and do it in 3 lines of code

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("sourcefile.txt");
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(?i)(?<=^id2\s*?:\s*?)\w*?(?=\s*?$)", "NewValue2",
                     RegexOptions.Multiline);
File.WriteAllText("outputfile.txt", text);
```

In the regex, **(?i)(?<=^id2\s*?:\s*?)\w*?(?=\s*?$)** means, find anything that starts with *id2* with any number of spaces before and after `:`, and replace the following string (any alpha numeric character, excluding punctuations) all the way 'till end of the line.  If you want to include punctuations, then replace **\w*?** with **.*?**

Answer (score -1):

You can use regexes to achieve this.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^ID\d+   :Value(\d+)\s*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("mytextfile");
foreach (string line in lines) {
    string replaced = re.Replace(target, processMatch);
    //Now do what you going to do with the value
}

string processMatch(Match m)
{
    var number = m.Groups[1];
    return String.Format("ID{0}   :NewValue{0}", number);
}
```